# Summing Columns conditionally prior to use in HeatMap GGPLOT2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a HeatMap in R from a dataset of about 7000 entries using ggplot2 in R but I am not feeling comfortable with the results due to the legend of my plot stating "Vol" values I know single instances have, and I am wanting to plot an aggregate volume for the Day of Month / Day of Week combination.

So my newbie assumption is ggplot2 does not auto-aggregate the values, or I am missing something prior to plotting.

Basically I want something similar to the following in Excel to be done on all 217 cells at the point of plotting or before.

`=SUMIFS(C2:C9999,D2:D9999,"1",F2:F9999,"Wed")`

Which for the first day of the Month that is on a Wednesday for example Excel states it is "6098822" and "6756753" for a 1st day of the month on a Thursday; more than the maximum density of the HeatMap below.

Most likely I am just missing a basic aggregation function to produce the correct aggregation combinations.

> Can someone point out what I should be doing and explain exactly what GGPLOT2 is doing below such as is it using the first combination it finds for the plot?

*Note: DoY ->1,365  DofM->1-31 DofW->Sun-Sat*

My data looks like the following:

```
> head(AC3,10)
   DD     Date   Vol DofM DoY DofW
1   1 01/01/97 28857    1   1  Wed
2   2 01/02/97 37757    2   2  Thu
3   3 01/03/97 41394    3   3  Fri
4   4 01/04/97 39614    4   4  Sat
5   5 01/05/97 32735    5   5  Sun
6   6 01/06/97 33536    6   6  Mon
7   7 01/07/97 33547    7   7  Tue
8   8 01/08/97 34205    8   8  Wed
9   9 01/09/97 35804    9   9  Thu
10 10 01/10/97 42895   10  10  Fri


>p<-ggplot(AC3,aes(DofM,DofW))
>p + geom_tile(aes(fill=Vol)) + scale_fill_gradient(low="white",   high="darkblue") + xlab("Day of Month") + ylab("Day of Week")
```

This produces the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test what `ggplot` is doing by contriving the data to make it easy to work out how `ggplot` is treating it.

For example, below is R-code to create a dataset that has the top 4 rows repeated on the last four rows. However, the `Vol` values are negative on the repeated bottom 4 rows. Run this to see:

```
# take in data similar to what was show in question
AC3<-scan(what=list(id=0,DD=0,Date="",Vol=0,DofM=0,DoY=0,DofW=""))
1   1 01/01/97 28857    1   1  Wed
2   2 01/02/97 37757    2   2  Thu
3   3 01/03/97 41394    3   3  Fri
4   4 01/04/97 39614    4   4  Sat
5   5 01/01/97 -8857    1   1  Wed
6   6 01/02/97 -7757    2   2  Thu
7   7 01/03/97 -1394    3   3  Fri
8   8 01/04/97 -9614    4   4  Sat

#turn into data.frame for ggplot
AC3<-as.data.frame(AC3)

# do the plottin'
require(ggplot2)
ggp2 <- ggplot(AC3,aes(DofM,DofW))
ggp2 <- ggp2 + geom_tile(aes(fill=Vol)) 
ggp2 <- ggp2 + scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="darkblue") 
ggp2 <- ggp2 + xlab("Day of Month") 
ggp2 <- ggp2 + ylab("Day of Week")
print(ggp2)
```

You can see ggplot just uses the last `Vol` value of combination `DofM,DofW`. Now to get to what you really want to do, sum up the repeated `Vol` values for `DofM,DofW` combinations. My weapon of choice is the `R` library `sqldf` (SQL data frame). It's a way of using SQL in R.

```
# need to install sqldf: install.packages("sqldf",dep=TRUE)
require(sqldf)
# sql query to add all Vol values for unique DofM, DofW combinations
AC4<-sqldf(paste("select DofM, DofW, sum(Vol) as newvol"
                ,"from AC3"
                ,"group by DofM, DofW"
                ))
# see if you agree with the output:
print(AC4)
```