# Using an ordered list to control display control display of points in R's GGPLOT2, such as days of the week

Tags: r, sorting, plot, ggplot2

I have read many posts on here about controlling the order of axis's when using GGPLOT2 in R and overriding the default 1.2.3... and alphabetical order of the points. At least based on my current understanding of R these examples are not meeting my requirements.

I want to display the days of the week in a particular order picking which day of the week I want to be the first day of the week, sometimes Sunday and other times Monday for example. The same could be applied to multiple other examples.

All of the examples I have found on here fall into one of two categories, neither of which meet my needs.

1. Using the order in the file (such as if B is the first value it will display before A then C) *OR*
2. List change the sort to ascending or descending based on the order.

Some of the others I specifically referenced (*which maybe I missed something?*).

- [How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)
- [controlling order of points in ggplot2 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706281/controlling-order-of-points-in-ggplot2-in-r)
- [Ordering bar plots with ggplot2 according to their size, i.e. numerical value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476440/ordering-bar-plots-with-ggplot2-according-to-their-size-i-e-numerical-value)
- [Specifying plot order with ggsubplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685379/specifying-plot-order-with-ggsubplot)
- [Order of legend entries in ggplot2 barplots with coord_flip()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299440/order-of-legend-entries-in-ggplot2-barplots-with-coord-flip?rq=1)
- [Control ggplot2 legend look without affecting the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356052/control-ggplot2-legend-look-without-affecting-the-plot?rq=1)

I also was reading on this [cheat sheet](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/) under "Create a tiled correlation plot (geom_tile())" which looks like they say they are ordering for the final output but their example graphic does not display them in this order but in the default alphabetical.

`#careful, I'm sorting the field names so that the ordering in the final plot is correct
thecor<-round(cor(nmmaps[,sort(c("death", "temp", "dewpoint", "pm10", "o3"))], method="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs"),2)`

As far as reproducabile, this is technically a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358532/summing-columns-conditionally-prior-to-use-in-heatmap-ggplot2-in-r), which after completing the describe step their my data looks like the following:

```html
DofM DofW  newvol
1     1  Fri 7412236
2     1  Mon 6713342
3     1  Sat 7138702
4     1  Sun 6246188
5     1  Thu 6756753
6     1  Tue 6817368
7     1  Wed 6098822
8     2  Fri 7688617
9     2  Mon 7073268
10    2  Sat 6777736
```

My code to produce the graphic looks like this:

```html
>p<-ggplot(AC4,aes(DofM,DofW))

>p + geom_tile(aes(fill=newvol)) + scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", mid="orange", high="darkred",na.value = "grey50", midpoint=6000000, breaks=c(4000000,4500000,5000000,5500000,6000000,6500000,7000000,7500000,8000000)) + xlab("Day of Month") + ylab("Day of Week") + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = 0:31)
```

Which produces the following graphic but my days of the week are out of order.

> I need them to be in a specific order of the Y-axis to *"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"*, **not** "Wed", "Tue", "Thu", "Sun", "Sat", "Mon", "Fri".  The X axis auto-order is just fine. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: You just need your data column to be a `factor` that has the levels in the correct order. `AC4$DofW = factor(AC4$DofW, levels = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")`. (As with numbers, the default is to start from the first on at the origin and go up, reverse the order if you prefer to start at the top and go down.)

Comment: And, there's an example of this in the first answer to the first question you link (suggested duplicate), there the variable is treatment and the desired order is Y, X, Z, and the code is `data$Treatment <- factor(data$Treatment, levels=c("Y", "X", "Z"))`

Comment: But you're right that the blog entry claims to demo this, but doesn't do it correctly or produce a correct plot.

Comment: @Gregor I saw that but how it was written it wasn't clear on how to apply it (still a newbie).. I played with it a bit based on your first comment and it is now more clear. I can delete it if you believe appropriate as it is now coming out correctly.